# how to refresh Auto react js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh, render, page-refresh

i am facing an issue in react page . i do auto refresh my react page

how shoud i do? anyone help plz..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    this.state = {   
      appointmentdata:[],
   }

  //fetch appointment data
  componentDidMount() {
axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments`)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  const appointmentdata = res.data; 
  setInterval(() => {
    this.setState({     
      appointmentdata :appointmentdata.appointments , 
    });
  }, 1000);  //refresh my api only
})

}


componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log("will");
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

I want to refresh my component data also.

please help me out?

Comment: Your http request should be inside the setInterval callback

Comment: can you write some code? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958452/angelsalazar)

Comment: i try , i can't do it plz help me [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958452/angelsalazar)